# Error using Count If

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an error using countif to check if values are present in an array.

I have a list of values called "All Points". There is a subset of these called "Plotted Points", that have coordinates. I am doing what should be a very simple check that all the "Plotted Points" are from the set of "All Points". To do this, I am using index-match on the a column called "No", to return TRUE is a point is within "Plotted Points" and false if it is not. I am then doing a COUNTIF TRUE.

My data is set up as such in two sheets:

ALL POINTS SHEET:

```
No.   Plotted
142   FALSE
543   FALSE
etc   etc
```

PLOTTED POINTS SHEET:

```
No.  EASTING  NORTHING
 142 406913   200386
 301 452776   314057
```

The formula in All Points Column B is `=IF(COUNTIF('Plotted Points'!A:A,'All Points'!A5) = 1,TRUE,FALSE)`. `'All Points'!A5 = 142`. In ALL POINTS B5, FALSE is returned. However 142 is in the range `'Plotted Points'!A:A`.

I have checked and this does not appear to be an issue with formatting. What is the error in my formula or my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's that `A5` doing in the formula? Also, you don't need the `IF`, a comparison results in `TRUE` or `FALSE` automatically. If I put in `B2` `=COUNTIF('Plotted Points'!A:A,'All Points'!A2) = 1` then fill down, I get `TRUE` in `B2` and `FALSE` in `B3`, as expected, and changing `'All Points'!A3` to `301` changes `'All Points'!A4` to `TRUE`, etc.